# Are PubKeys from multisig scripts addresses?

Tags: multi-signature, p2sh

Are PubKeys from multisig scripts addresses? I.e. are they ever HASH160'd and re-used as normal P2PKH addresses in the future transactions?

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing that prevents that from happening, but it's not recommended. In general, it is not recommended to reuse public keys.

Comment: Are there known examples when multisig keys have been reused as P2PKH addresses?

Comment: You could scan the blockchain to find some, I'm certain they exist. But I don't know of any off the top of my head.